# schedule Docker RUN command on windows monthly

Tags: windows, docker, schedule

i would like schedule the command: "docker run -it --cpus 4 q2c-spark:latest"  to run monthly on 2nd working day morning on a windows.
How should i do it?

command on windows  " docker run -it --cpus 4 q2c-spark:latest"

These can be run in cmd windows

it is a spark scala app

i need to trigger the docker command to run monthly

Comment: you can run with task scheduler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

Answer (score 1):

You can use from command line (CMD shell session on Windows) the [`schtasks.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814596/how-to-use-schtasks-exe-to-schedule-tasks-in-windows-server-2003) command.

See an [example here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-task-using-task-scheduler-command-prompt)

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC MONTHLY /D 15 /TN "FOLDERPATH\TASKNAME" /TR "C:\SOURCE\FOLDER\APP-OR-SCRIPT" /ST HH:MM
```

For example, the 15th of each month:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC MONTHLY /D 15 /TN "MyTasks\Notepad task" /TR "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" /ST 11:00
```

Comment: Hey Von, how can i write a docker run command in the SCHTASK?

Comment: @JudithTan Replace `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` by `C:\path\to\my\script.bat`, with `script.bat` being a script where you can set the PATH to include docker, and where you can type your docker command. In other words, script it first: once it is working as a script, you can reference that script in a `SHTASKS` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a `docker run` command in Windows Task Scheduler, without the need to create a `.bat` file.

- *Action* is `Start a program`
- *The Program/script* is `docker`
- *Add arguments (optional)* contains the rest of the command, `run ...` + the image name and any other arguments
- *Start in* is the directory where you want it to run, e.g., where your environment variables file is

In the end it looks like this: [image]